# Variable as part of column name

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering if possible to do this:

I have multiple columns with same name except for last digits:

Round1, Round2, Round3, Round4...etc

I have also defined a variable that I need to update manually depending on which column Id like to be taken into account in all of my queries instead of updating each one separately (time saving)

```
$round_number="4"; // round 4 selected for example here
```

then this is one my queries, I need it to select the round number defined by the variable above, I tried this:

```
SELECT *, sum(Round'$round_number') as round_total from mytable where group_name LIKE 'fighters%' group by side order by round_total desc
```

as expected, the above query failed...

Any help is welcome

Thanks fellas
EDIT (actual query as is)

```
$latest_week="4"; // UPDATE ALERT HERE
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, sum(SR) as SRT, sum(RS'. $latest_week . ')      as RST FROM na_july16_resources_v2 where group_name LIKE 'fighters%' group by side order by RST desc")
```

or die(mysql_error());

Comment: You will probably need to use `dynamic sql` unless you know the number of potential columns.  If you do, then you could possibly use `case` statements instead...

Comment: If each round is a separate column, you most definitely have the wrong database design

Comment: Ive always been thinking that, @e4c5. I should put the rounds as rows, shouldn't I?

Comment: yes, each round should be a row that makes the whole thing more managable. I guess you are making a tournament management software?

Comment: Excatly, @e4c5. I think this is the way I should go...I have to re-design my database, it's worth the time, otherwise Im gonna hot more walls down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a variable be read inside a string by using double quotes. Strings in double quotes (and not single quotes) are parsed for variable names. So you could do this to use the variable inside the query:

```
"SELECT *, sum(Round$round_number) as round_total from mytable where group_name LIKE 'fighters%' group by side order by round_total desc"
```

As Jaime said you could also just concatenate the strings using a dot.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP strings are concatenated with a dot.
`$sql = 'SELECT *, sum(Round' . $round_number . ') as round_total from mytable where group_name LIKE \'fighters%\' group by side order by round_total desc'`

Comment: Thanks, @Jaime. I tried but still failing, Im sure im doing something wrong so I ve edited my question by added the actual query as is hoping that youd maybe spot the culprit...

Comment: Can you post the schema of that table?

Comment: which1ispink got it right meanwhile but thanks for your reply anyway :)